# Using Dictionary into the Clase_Initialize Method

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use a dictionary into my class User to stock a list of applications, create with the class `Applications`.

Please find my classes here:

The `Users` class:

```
Option Explicit

'Variables Declaration
Public Name As String
Public FirstName As String
Public Mail As String
Public Phone As String
Public Zone As String
Public Apps As New Scripting.Dictionary

'Initialize Class
Private Sub Class_initialize()

Dim i As Integer
Dim a As New Applications

    i = 2
    While Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        a.SetName = Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Apps.Add i - 2, a
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

And the `Applications` class:

```
'Variables Declaration
Public Name As String
Public Index As String
Public Statut As String

'Initialize Class
Private Sub Class_initialize()
    Statut = "None"
End Sub
```

I delete the LET and GET function for more clarity.

So how can I optimize this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create only one `Applications` object, and you change it in the loop.

What you need is to create a new `Applications` object each time inside the loop.

```
Dim a As Applications
i = 2
While Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
    Set a = New Applications                      ' <~~~~
    a.Name = Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value
    Apps.Add i - 2, a
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Maybe you want to use the name of the app as key? In this case, change:

```
    Apps.Add i - 2, a
```

into

```
    Apps.Add a.Name, a
```

Then later to retrieve an app (given the name) from the dictionary:

```
dim a as Applications  
set a = User.Apps("someAppName")
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I access/change an attribute of my Object now ?
I tried: ?User.Apps(a)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're after:

```
Option Explicit

'Variables Declaration
Public name As String
Public FirstName As String
Public Mail As String
Public Phone As String
Public Zone As String
Public Apps As New Scripting.Dictionary

'Initialize Class
Private Sub Class_initialize()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Applications

    i = 2
    While Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        Set a = New Applications
        a.SetName Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Apps.Add i - 2, a
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

where I supposed you have some `SetName` sub in your `Applications` Class, like

```
Public Sub SetName(passedName As String)
    name = passedName
End Sub
```

otherwise change:

```
a.SetName Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

to:

```
a.Name = Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 2).Value
```